# How to create a 720x480 blank mpg

Tags: ffmpeg

In order to join some video clip(720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3]) and leave two seconds blank gap between each one, i try to make an blank clip by code

```
ffmpeg -t 2 -s 720x480 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 29.97 -i /dev/zero -f lavfi -i anullsrc -shortest empty_720x480.mpg
```

but when i try to concat clips,

```
-filter_complex "[0:v:0]setsar=8/9[v0];[1:v:0][1:a:0][v0][0:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][v0][0:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]"
```

an error occurs

```
Input link in3:v0 parameters (size 720x480, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (720x480, SAR 8:9)
```

I have try create an 720x540 first and scale to 720x480(), but still not the same with 720x480 [SAR 200:219 DAR 100:73].

I have no idel how to solve it, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the SAR during creation.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:r=30000/1001:s=720x480,setsar=8/9[out0];anullsrc[out1] -t 2 -f vob empty_720x480.mpg
```

Then, during filtering,

```
-filter_complex "[1:v:0][1:a:0][0:v][0:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][0:v][0:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]"
```

I assume the rest of your command is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But
i run create empty command an error showed:

At least one output file must be specified

What should i can? Thanks.

Comment: I try change command to 
    
`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:r=30000/1001:s=720x480,setsar=8/9 -f lavfi -i anullsrc[out1] -t 2 empty_720x480.mpg`
    
or 
    
`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:r=30000/1001:s=720x480,setsar=8/9 -t 2 empty_720x480.mpg`

, But result is the same

`Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 720x480 [SAR 200:219 DAR 100:73], 104857 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc`
SAR is 200:219 not 8/9.

Comment: Input #0, lavfi, from 'color=black:r=30000/1001:s=720x480,setsar=8/9[out0]':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
At least one output file must be specified
-bash: anullsrc[out1]: command not found

Comment: I known it...; is comman seprator in unix like env. i change to `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=black:r=30000/1001:s=720x480,setsar=8/9[out0];anullsrc[out1]" -t 2 empty_720x480.mpg` is OK.

Comment: The meta of created file is `Input #0, mpeg, from '/Users/peter/Downloads/empty_720x480.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:02.01, start: 0.522456, bitrate: 529 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 720x480 [SAR 200:219 DAR 100:73], 104857 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 384 kb/s`

Comment: is any possibility to make an blank video with size=720x480, sar=8/9, dsp-size=720x540? Thks.

Comment: Thanks. I don't notice `-f vob` been added. I works. Thanks.